# Интерфейс в адаптере, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Учу котлин, хочу реализовать в адаптере для `RecyclerView` интерфейс, посредством которого я буду возвращать в активити какое - то значение. Ничерта не получается, прошу подсказать по некоторым вопросам(в конце).

На Java я бы написал это так(интерфейс: `OnAnimalClickListener`):

Адаптер:

```
public class PackContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PackContentAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private OnAnimalClickListener onAnimalClickListener;
    ...
    void setOnAnimalClickListener(OnAnimalClickListener onAnimalClickListener) {
        this.onAnimalClickListener = onAnimalClickListener;
    }
    ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.bind(item);
    }
    ...
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ...
        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ...
        }

        void bind(Item item) {
            ...             
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onAnimalClickListener.onAnimalClicked();
        }
    }

    public interface OnAnimalClickListener {
        void onAnimalClicked();
    }
}
```

Активити:

```
contentAdapter.setOnAnimalClickListener(() -> //doSomething);
```

Что пишу на котлине(названия чуть другие):

Адаптер:

```
class PacksAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<PacksAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var onPackClickListener: OnPackClickListener? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }

    var packList: ArrayList<Animal> = ArrayList()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cell_animalpack_4, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(packList[0], context)
    }


 class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view),View.OnClickListener {
        ...
        fun bind(pack: AnimalPackFull, context: Context) {
            ...
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            onPackClickListener.
        }
    }

    interface OnPackClickListener {
        fun onPackClicked(packId: Int)
    }
}
```

Активити:

```
(recycler_packs.adapter as PacksAdapter).onPackClickListener = PacksAdapter.OnPackClickListener()
```

Вопросы:

1) Вот тут недаром код недописан:

```
 override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                onPackClickListener.
            }
```

Дело в том, что я из метода не вижу мой `onPackClickListener`, написано что он `Unresolved`. Это ещё почему?

2) В активити я получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не могу понять, что от меня вообще хотят?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы внутренний класс имел доступ к экземпляру внешнего, он должен быть помечен `inner`.

И еще вы пытаетесь инстанцировать интерфейс, не реализовав метод. Это можно сделать так:

```
val listener = object: OnPackClickListener {
    override fun onPackClicked(packId: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }
}
```

Но это не то, что вам нужно, потому, что в kotlin вместо функциональных интерфейсов java используют функциональные типы, в данном случае `(Int) -> Unit`

Не поленитесь, пройдите пару курсов по kotlin на [stepik.org](http://stepik.org), станет понятнее что к чему.

[Введение в Kotlin JVM](https://stepik.org/course/5448)

[Разработка Android-приложений на Kotlin](https://stepik.org/course/4792)